# Error in App Metro with DevDefined.OAuth

Tags: c#, oauth, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am developing an app metro for windows 8. I use DevDefined.Oauth for authenticate but gives the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system can not find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

That is because .NET for Metro supports only small [subset of common assemblies and classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232.aspx). `System.Web` is not supported at all so you cannot use that library in Metro application.